# Ungrouping, "flatten", a case class that is a composite of other case classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Generally what I am trying to achieve:
I think I would like to remove the case classes from the RDD, but keep the RDD, and am unsure how to do that.

Specificatlly what I am trying to do:
What I am trying to achieve is to turn each row of an RDD into json. But the json can only be a list a key:value pairs. When I turn it into json in it's current form I get

```
{"CCABINDeviceDataPartial":
    {"Tran_Id":"1234weqr",
     "TranData":{"Processor_Id":"qqq","Merchant_Id":"1234"},
     "BillingAndShippingData":{"Billing_City":"MyCity","Billing_State":"State","Billing_Zip":"000000","Billing_Country":"MexiCanada","Shipping_City":"MyCity","Shipping_State":"State","Shipping_Zip":"000000","Shipping_Country":"USico"}
     ...
    }
}
```

What I want is

```
{"Tran_Id":"1234weqr",
 "Processor_Id":"qqq",
 "Merchant_Id":"1234",
 "Billing_City":"MyCity",
 "Billing_State":"State",
 "Billing_Zip":"000000",
 "Billing_Country":"MexiCanada",
 "Shipping_City":"MyCity",
 "Shipping_State":"State",
 "Shipping_Zip":"000000",
 "Shipping_Country":"USico"
 ...
}
```

I have what I call a parent case class that looks like this:

```
case class CCABINDeviceDataPartial(Tran_Id: String, TranData: TranData,
    BillingAndShippingData: BillingAndShippingData, AcquirerData: AcquirerData,
    TimingData: TimingData, RBD_Tran_Id: String, DeviceData1: DeviceData1, ACS_Time: Long,
    Payfone_Alias: String, TranStatusData: TranStatusData, Centurion_BIN_Class: String,
    BankData: BankData, DeviceData2: DeviceData2, ACS_Host: String,
    DeviceData3: DeviceData3, txn_status: String, Device_Type: String,
    TranOutcome: TranOutcome, AcsData: AcsData, DateTimeData: DateTimeData)
```

Now TranData, BillingAndShippingData, AcquirerData, and some others are also case classes. I presume this was done to get around the 21 or 22 element limit on case classes. If you "unroll" everything there are 76 elements in total.

My only working idea is to break out the case classes into dataframes and then join them together one at a time. This seems a bit onerous and I am hoping that there is a way to just "flatten" the RDD. I have looked at the [API documentation for RDDs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) but don't see anything that obvious.

**Additional Notes**

This is how I currently convert things to json.
First I convert the RDD to a dataframe with

```
def rddDistinctToTable(txnData: RDD[CCABINDeviceDataPartial], instanceSpark:SparkService,
    tableName: String): DataFrame = {

  import instanceSpark.sql.implicits._
  val fullTxns = txnData.filter(x => x.Tran_Id != "0")
  val uniqueTxns = rddToDataFrameHolder(fullTxns.distinct()).toDF()
  uniqueTxns.registerTempTable(tableName)
  return uniqueTxns

}
```

Then to convert to json and write to Elasticsearch with

```
sparkStringJsonRDDFunctions(uniqueTxns.toJSON)
  .saveJsonToEs(instanceSpark.sc.getConf.get("es.resource"))
```

Comment: Updating to Scala 2.11 is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and simple solution:

- convert RDD to DataFrame
- use `select` to flatten records (you can use dots to access nested objects like `df.select("somecolumn.*", "another.nested.column")`)
- use `write.json` to write as JSON